# scrollIntoViewOption is not working in major browsers?

Tags: javascript

Is there any alternative way to achive the same behaviour of "`element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });`" Since it is not working in higher versions in chrome and mozilla & safari as well.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

Answer (score 1):

You could use a fallback if the function does not exist:

`if ((!'scrollIntoView' in document.body) {...}`

With some library like jQuery or pure JS code:

jQuery:

```
function scrollToElementId(id) {
    const $element = $('#' + id);

    if ($element.length) {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $element.offset().top
        }, 500);
    }
}
```

TypeScript:

```
export class ScrollToService {
    public smoothScroll(eID: string) {
        const elm = document.getElementById(eID);

        if (!elm) return;

        const stopY = this.elmYPosition(elm);

        this.smoothScrollToPosition(stopY);
    }

    private scrollTo(yPoint: number, duration: number) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            window.scrollTo(0, yPoint);
        }, duration);
        return;
    }

    private smoothScrollToPosition(stopY: number) {
        const startY = this.currentYPosition();
        const distance = stopY > startY ? stopY - startY : startY - stopY;

        if (distance < 100) {
            window.scrollTo(0, stopY);
            return;
        }
        let speed = Math.round(distance / 100);
        if (speed >= 20) speed = 20;
        const step = Math.round(distance / 15);
        let leapY = stopY > startY ? startY + step : startY - step;
        let timer = 0;
        if (stopY > startY) {
            for (let i = startY; i < stopY; i += step) {
                this.scrollTo(leapY, timer * speed);
                leapY += step;
                if (leapY > stopY) leapY = stopY;
                timer++;
            }
            return;
        }
        for (let i = startY; i > stopY; i -= step) {
            this.scrollTo(leapY, timer * speed);
            leapY -= step;
            if (leapY < stopY) leapY = stopY;
            timer++;
        }
    }

    private currentYPosition(): number {
        // Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        if (self.pageYOffset) {
            return self.pageYOffset;
        }

        // Internet Explorer 6 - standards mode
        if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop) {
            return document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        }
        // Internet Explorer 6, 7 and 8
        if (document.body.scrollTop) {
            return document.body.scrollTop;
        }

        return 0;
    }

    private elmYPosition(elm): number {
        let y: number = elm.offsetTop;
        let node = elm;
        while (node.offsetParent && node.offsetParent != document.body) {
            node = <any>node.offsetParent;
            y += node.offsetTop;
        }
        return y;
    }
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var ScrollToService = /** @class */ (function () {
    function ScrollToService() {
    }
    ScrollToService.prototype.smoothScroll = function (eID) {
        var elm = document.getElementById(eID);
        if (!elm)
            return;
        var stopY = this.elmYPosition(elm);
        this.smoothScrollToPosition(stopY);
    };
    ScrollToService.prototype.scrollTo = function (yPoint, duration) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            window.scrollTo(0, yPoint);
        }, duration);
        return;
    };
    ScrollToService.prototype.smoothScrollToPosition = function (stopY) {
        var startY = this.currentYPosition();
        var distance = stopY > startY ? stopY - startY : startY - stopY;
        if (distance < 100) {
            window.scrollTo(0, stopY);
            return;
        }
        var speed = Math.round(distance / 100);
        if (speed >= 20)
            speed = 20;
        var step = Math.round(distance / 15);
        var leapY = stopY > startY ? startY + step : startY - step;
        var timer = 0;
        if (stopY > startY) {
            for (var i = startY; i < stopY; i += step) {
                this.scrollTo(leapY, timer * speed);
                leapY += step;
                if (leapY > stopY)
                    leapY = stopY;
                timer++;
            }
            return;
        }
        for (var i = startY; i > stopY; i -= step) {
            this.scrollTo(leapY, timer * speed);
            leapY -= step;
            if (leapY < stopY)
                leapY = stopY;
            timer++;
        }
    };
    ScrollToService.prototype.currentYPosition = function () {
        // Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        if (self.pageYOffset) {
            return self.pageYOffset;
        }
        // Internet Explorer 6 - standards mode
        if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop) {
            return document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        }
        // Internet Explorer 6, 7 and 8
        if (document.body.scrollTop) {
            return document.body.scrollTop;
        }
        return 0;
    };
    ScrollToService.prototype.elmYPosition = function (elm) {
        var y = elm.offsetTop;
        var node = elm;
        while (node.offsetParent && node.offsetParent != document.body) {
            node = node.offsetParent;
            y += node.offsetTop;
        }
        return y;
    };
    return ScrollToService;
}());
```

Comment: I don't think it meet as expected because we don't know the values of "`behavior: 'smooth'`"  since in pure javascript we're hard coding the speed values.

Comment: Quote: https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view-1/#concept-smooth-scroll 
'smooth'
The scrolling box is scrolled in a smooth fashion using a user-agent-defined timing function over a user-agent-defined period of time. User agents should follow platform conventions, if any.
I would say, still better than instant jumping to the position with any "smooth" defined scroll duration.

Comment: Cool, the problem is user wants exact behavior thats y I'm worrying the time... is there a way to build it in polyfill ?

Comment: I did not find any values on the page for the scrolling implementation, since it is "user agent defined". Maybe one could read the values and implement this in the scrolling with a fallback. 
If you combine the above code, you could write a polyfill, yes